# create a list of pandas data frame variable names with similar spelling

Tags: python, regex, list, pandas

In my environment I have a list of several pandas data frames that are similarly named.

For example:

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np 
 df_abc = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD')
 df_xyz = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD')
 df_2017 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD')
 ...  potentially others
```

I'd like to create list that automatically figures which data frames are in my environment and pulls them into a list dynamically.

```
 list_of_dfs = ['df_abc','df_xyz','df_2017', 'df_anything else']  
  # except done dynamically.   In this example anything beginning with 'df_' 
#  list_of_dfs = function_help(begins with 'df_')
```

Answer (score 2):

`globals()` should return a dictionary of variable_name:variable_value for the global variables.

If you want a list of defined variables with names starting with 'df_' you could do:

```
list_of_dfs = [variable for variable in globals().keys()
               if variable.startswith('df_')]
```

I reckon there has to be a better way than storing your dataframes globally, and relying on globals() to fetch their variable names though. Maybe store them all inside a dictionary?:

```
dataframes = {}
dataframes['df_1'] = pd.DataFrame()
dataframes['df_2'] = pd.DataFrame()

list_of_dfs = dataframes.keys()
```

Comment: Plus one for answer and advice

Comment: @L. Alvarez    Sorry if I wasn't being clear - I don't want to store the data frames in a list...just the variable names of the data frames in a list.   .

Comment: My solution stores the variable names in a list. The call to .keys() extracts the variable names from the dictionary of the variable_name:variable_value  returned by globals().